# Is there any evidence of scifi SE influencing the Force Awakens?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but it would be cool if we could point to specific details of TFA and note influence of questions on scifi SE.  If I was writing a new entry of an existing scifi franchise I know I would be mining SE for some thoughts and ideas and other research.

Comment: WOAH, I WAS JUST THINKING THE SAME THING!!!

Comment: Related: [Have we had ANY professionals participate in SFF?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2474/21267)

Comment: That's actually a not great  idea as it would open you to litigation from people who could point to you ripping off their ideas. It's why some companies don't even allow fans to send in suggestions.

Comment: Wanting a certain type of casting is not nearly the same thing as suggesting plot elements.

Comment: @phantom42's concern seems justified based on the [CC by-SA license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that StackExchange uses. In order to reuse original ideas posted on this site, film-makers and script-writers would need to provide attribution, which seems unlikely to happen for commercial films (but entirely possible for fan-flicks). This concern has been raised previously on StackOverflow: [Possible workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/#12539), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/)

Comment: No way. Most of the answers here are copy-paste from various sff sources and their wikis. what this site lacks is originality, why on earth would someone come here for ideas???